# How would the opponent defraud this secure communication?

Tags: encryption, mac, stream-cipher

I am new in the cryptography and the information security problems, I try to understand things as much as I can and I know it's really complicated in the beginning.

Considering the communication protocol between a bank and its machines is standard and we have got an opponent who knows a little bit the way the information is encrypted. Of course this wouldn't cause a problem since the code that the bank uses is considered secure ( a secure Stream Cipher ).

The problem is the bank does not use a MAC. In that case, how would the hacker defraud the bank ? I thought that the MAC doesn't have any relation with the confidently ?

I appreciate your help/ explanations

Comment: MAC doesn't deal with confidentiality, it deals with integrity. So the attacker can attack integrity of the communications. Am I missing something?

Comment: @mikeazo not having integrity protection might enable a break of confidentiality too, as it can enable chosen-ciphertext attacks like in this XML-encryption attack some years ago.

Comment: So the problem is that the data can be integrated ? Even with a secure encryption method ? Like how would he integrate something to the message?

Comment: Stream ciphers operate on each *bit* of the message individually. If you flip a bit, the corresponding plaintext bit will be flipped as well. If you know the data structure and know the values you're interested in you can figure out which bits to flip.

Comment: Okay, so since the stream ciphers operate on each bit of the message individually, then if we flip a bit, the original bit that corresponds the plaintext will be flipped as well. So then if we add or remove a bit, then the whole message would be corrupted.

So the hacker would only add a bit or remove a bit or flip bits. Is this considered as defrauding  a bank ?

Comment: Adding and removing bits would actually lead to random data being decrypted. But if you can flip bits and you know where the recipient and the amount of a transaction are located and you know the original values, you can calculate the difference and inject this one (i.e. flipping some bits)

Comment: Okay I appreciate your comments really that clarified to me a lot of things. But I don't get it how he would calculate the difference by flipping bits ? I mean If he knows where the amount of a transaction is located and he knows the original value, so ? what do you mean by calculating the difference and how would he inject the amount IF the amount is encrypted already so he would know that this part of encrypted data is associated to the amount.. @SEJPM

Comment: I'll quickly write a full and formal answer and I guess this will clarify everything (and our comment police can clean up here ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an attacker to be able to actually successfully break the security of the bank, we need to make a few assumptions, which I'll state here:

- A stream cipher without proper authentication is used.
- The attacker knows the data format the bank uses.
- The attacker knows the recipient and amount of a transaction (i.e. the *interesting values*), which he may change.

---

First we need to consider how a stream cipher works. Most stream ciphers work by taking a key and an initialization vector and expanding this to a long *keystream*. The keystream $K$ is used to encrypt a message $M$ to the ciphertext $C$ as follows: $C=K\oplus M$ where $\oplus$ denotes bitwise XOR.

Now assume that the message being actually sent by the bank is $M$ containing a valid recipient and a valid transaction amount. Now further assume the attacker wants to replace this by $M'$ where he increases the amount and makes himself the recipient. One nice thing about bitwise XOR is that $a\oplus a = 0$ holds. Now the attacker can calculate the difference $\Delta=M\oplus M'$. He now replaces $C$ by $C'=C\oplus \Delta$. Now observe that $$C'=C\oplus\Delta=(K\oplus M)\oplus (M\oplus M')=K\oplus M'$$ which will decrypt to $M'$ by XOR'ing $K$ in again.

---

[As requested by Maarten in the comments:](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/33104/how-would-the-opponent-defraud-this-secure-communication/33111#comment77162_33104)

### The (actual) Example

Assume that `0001001001100101100000001011010010` is the (legitimate) recipient ID.
Assume that `0000010111011100` is the legitimate transaction amount in USD.
Assume that `1001001100100100011110000010001010` is the attacker's ID.
Assume that `1100001101010000` is the attacker's preferred enrichment.
Assume that the message encoding consists of simple concatenation of the recipient ID and amount.
Assume that  `01011000011010011001110010010110101100010100011100` is the keystream.
The message $M$ is then `00010010011001011000000010110100100000010111011100` and the (legitimate) ciphertext $C$ is `01001010000011000001110000100010001100000011000000`.
The malicious message $M'$ would be 
`10010011001001000111100000100010101100001101010000` and therefore the 
difference $\Delta$ would be 
`10000001010000011111100010010110001100011010001100`
Thereby $C'$ is
`11001011010011011110010010110100000000011001001100` which will be decoded to `10010011001001000111100000100010101100001101010000` which is $M'$ and thereby the attacker will receive 50k USD.

Comment: Excellent explanation, but could you add something tangible like changing the amount or bank number within a transaction?

Comment: Okay I love the way you explained it, but I don't get it why would the attack know M ? You want to say that he has the C and the way it is encrypted, so he decrypts the C, obtain M , change values and calculate the difference and send the new C' ?

Comment: @Zok Many times the structure of the messages is well known. Actually, you may know the contents as well. For instance it is quite possible for an attacker to send a bill for 10 euro to a company. This one is likely paid simply because it takes too much time to check the bill. What if the attacker than changes the amount to 100 times as much? As for banks: there are many banks so usually the operate on well defined standards (which very likely use MAC's by now, we can only hope).